# IServiceCollection does not contain a definition for AddAzureClients

Tags: c#, azure, .net-6.0

I am trying to add a blob service client for dependency injection.
I'm using the latest version of `Microsoft.Extensions.Azure`, however my service collection does not contain the extension method of `AddAzureClients`. The service collection is of type `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection`.

I've not really found anything for this issue by researching online. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Probably something very simple I'm missing!

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace MY.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAzureClients(builder => // IServiceCollection does not contain a definition for AddAzureClients
            {
                builder.AddBlobServiceClient(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BlobStorage"));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved this, not sure why it behaved this way.
Despite me having `using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure` in my `.cs` file and it appearing as installed, the package wasn't actually installed to the project. After installing it manually in NuGet package manager it works as expected.